# Creating a DbSet<T> from an Expression in order to create a dynamic querying service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I'm trying to create a dynamic querying service using *Entity Framework*.

My approach is to somehow create a light client for creating queries over DTO's, producing an `IQueryable<T>` or an `Expression` and then, ship that query\expression over the network to an execution service that will translate the `IQueryable<T>` \ `Expression` into SQL, run it and return an `IEnumerable<S>`.

My thought was to use `Enumerable.Empty<T>.AsQueryable()` to create the queries, but then when I need to execute the queries I need the ability to translate them to SQL - and that's how *Entity Framework* is suppose to help me.

*Entity Framework* does it's magic using classes that implement `IQueryable<T>` like `DbSet<T>` and `DbQuery<T>`.
I can create a client which will create `IQueryable<T>'s` using an *Entity Framework* dummy `DbContext`, so I can basically create queries and have the ability on the client to produce the SQL from them.

I tried to mix between frameworks and use *Entity Framework* for producing SQL from my `IQueryable<T>'s` and then executing it using *Dapper*, but it gets complicated when nested navigation properties are involved and I still want the ability to modify the queries using custom `Expression<Func<T,T>>'s` on my service. 
So creating queries on the client and sending SQL to the service isn't really a suitable solution for me.

Is there any way I can create a `DbSet<T>` from an `Expression`? Or somehow "serialize" a `DbSet<T>`?
Is there any other recommended framework that could help me achieve this functionality?

**Edit** -> Here is some pseduo code of what I'm trying to achieve:

Client:

```
var query = QueryCreator
.Get<MyDto>()
.Include(d => d.MySonDto)
.Where(d => d.IsActive)
.OrderBy(d => d.MySonDto.Date)
.Take(10);

 var result = service.Query(query); // or `service.Query(query.Expression);`
```

My service needs to somehow receive the query, translate it to SQL, execute it and run it against a database.

Now I thought about using *Entity Framework* for the translation and now my main problem is how to serialize an `IQueryable<T>` or an `Expression` and create a `DbSet<T>` from it on the service?
(`DbSet<T>.Parse(expression)` would be nice :-) )

Comment: I've had enormous headaches attempting a similar thing to what you're proposing in the past, especially around serializing generics and expression trees. Have you considered exposing an OData endpoint on your service layer? E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: @ChrisPickford - I thought about an OData solution which is weaker. I'm still trying my luck with this path since I have additional requirements that I didn't specify here.

Comment: Can you add a pseudo-code example?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I've added some pseudo-code. Hope that it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: Can you make the `DbContext` statically typed (i.e add the known entities) or must it be completely generic (i.e for any database/table)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - The DTO's and the context will be static. The query will be dynamic and I will insert dynamic code using custom Expression's.

Comment: You might be interested in this library: https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq

Comment: @Evk - That could be a nice start. Now I need to somehow create a DbSet<T> from that expression and leverage the features of EntityFramework. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Givent that you know `T` (as per the comments), you can create the query with the received `Expression` using `CreateQuery`:

```
var context = new YourContext();
var data = context.Set<T>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Provider.CreateQuery(yourReceivedExpressionOfTEntity)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can get the `DbSet<T>` in an easier way using new `MyDbContext().Set<T>()`.
I don't need the second code section since a `DbSet<T>` is a `IQueryable<T>`. I can always cast it if I don't want `DbSet<T>` traces in my code.
My problem is how can I ship the query and create a `DbSet<T>` from a query\expression.

Comment: @AmirPopovich `Set<T>()` does not work if you don't know what `T` is. You don't need to create a `DbSet<T>`, you need to apply your `Expression` to the `DbSet<T>` (at least that's what can be understood from your question)

Comment: I know what T is and even if I receive T as a type I can always use `MakeGenericMethod` or other reflection solutions for retrieving the `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: The `DbSet<T>` is only for making changes on the Db, for queries you use `IQueryable<T>`, so not really sure what you are asking now

Comment: A `DbSet<T> ` is an Entity Framework class that implements `IQueryable<T>` and other interfaces. You can cast a `DbSet<T>` into a `IQueryable<T>`. Basically, the DbSet (or the DbQuery<T> that it inherits) gives you the capabilities of translating the query into SQL. That is something you cannot achieve with simply an `IQueryable<T>` that you create from `Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable`.

Comment: @AmirPopovich That's why I used `.Provider.CreateQuery`